# InternetExplorerDriver StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have the following Selenium test code:

```
waitForElementList(driver, timeout, By.xpath(elementA);
waitForElementList(driver, timeout, By.xpath(elementB);
waitForElementList(driver, timeout, By.xpath(elementC);
waitForElementList(driver, timeout, By.xpath(elementD);
waitForElementList(driver, timeout, By.xpath(elementE);
waitForElementList(driver, timeout, By.xpath(elementF);

List<WebElement> elementA = driver.findElements(By.xpath(elementA));
List<WebElement> elementB = driver.findElements(By.xpath(elementB));
List<WebElement> elementC = driver.findElements(By.xpath(elementC));
List<WebElement> elementD = driver.findElements(By.xpath(elementD));
List<WebElement> elementE = driver.findElements(By.xpath(elementE));
List<WebElement> elementF = driver.findElements(By.xpath(elementF));

for(int i = 0; i < elementA.size(); i++){
    int id = Integer.valueOf(elementA.get(i).getAttribute("class"));
    //doing things with the other elements
}

public static void waitForElementList(WebDriver driver, int timeout, final By locator){
    FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
       .withTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
       .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
       .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
       .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class);

    wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, List<WebElement>>() {
        public List<WebElement> apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return driver.findElements(locator);
        }
    });
}
```

If I run this piece of code in any browser than Internet Explorer it works correctly. But if I run it in Internet Explorer it sometimes crashes at the line where it wants to get the Attribute "class". There appears a StaleElementReferenceException. The funny thing is this exception only appears on Windows 7 IE9 but not Windows XP IE8.
I googled a lot how to get around this but no solution helped me. This exception appears if an element has refreshed or something but between the waitForElementList()-methods an the getAttribute call is no refresh. If I only run the first waitForElementList()-method (for elementA) and not the other waitForElementList()-methods it works. I don't know what to do now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Refresh can be triggered by javascript code on page.
It leaves room for some IE-only page content, which is messing with you.

I'd re-arrange the code to extract elements' attributes as soon as possible as temporary or even permanent solution. And it seems like you already know how to do that.

---

UPD:

If nothing you can think about helps, use 3rd party library for extracting the actual attribute values, and use selenium just for clicks and browsing.

Here is the example of using both `selenium` and `lxml` in python:

```
from lxml import etree
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox  # IE, or Chrome


SEARCH_EDITBOX_CSS_CLASS_XPATH = '//input[@id="lst-ib"]/@class'

browser = Firefox()
browser.get('http://google.com')
html = browser.page_source

tree = etree.fromstring(html, parser=etree.HTMLParser())
css_classes = tree.xpath(SEARCH_EDITBOX_CSS_CLASS_XPATH)

print css_classes
# prints out list of 'class' attributes for each of elements found:
# ['gsfi']
```

Once you put whole page source code into the variable – site scripts will not change it, and  you will have unlimited time for playing with it.

Comment: actually this helped at first, but the StaleElementReferenceException still appears from time to time. This makes it almost impossible to write tests for the IE. I mean, you have two lines of code: the first one is "findElement(...)" the second one is something like "getText", "getAttribute" or whatever. And between these two lines of code, Selenium tells me that the element is no longer valid? I mean, this is a time of milli seconds, how can that be? It really makes it impossible to write stable tests with IE. Any further help to this issue? Would be very nice, thanks a lot!

Comment: @user1169166, I've updated the answer to keep it all together.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'll try that.
But still is there no real solution for that? There are no java scripts in the background which manipulate the DOM in the background so I can't understand why Selenium tells me the WebElement is no longer valid. It is indeed valid. that's what I don't understand.